# css image positioning (rows and columns)

Tags: html, css

I have a question concerning the positioning of images in CSS and HTML. I would like to make an implementation, as in the picture (NO2) shown.

My first Idea was the *table* in HTML, but the problem is there, that I don't know how to to position two pictures in a row..

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="pic_mountain.jpg"style="width:100px;height:50px;"></td>
    <td><img src="pic_mountain.jpg"style="width:100px;height:50px;"></td>
    <td><img src="pic_mountain.jpg"style="width:100px;height:50px;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="pic_mountain.jpg"style="width:100px;height:50px;"></td>
    <td><img src="pic_mountain.jpg"style="width:100px;height:50px;"></td>
    <td><img src="pic_mountain.jpg"style="width:100px;height:50px;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="pic_mountain.jpg"style="width:100px;height:50px;"></td>
    <td><img src="pic_mountain.jpg"style="width:100px;height:50px;"></td>
    <td><img src="pic_mountain.jpg"style="width:100px;height:50px;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

How would such an arrangement of the pictures look in CSS and HTML?

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Probably using `float:left`, `margin-left` and the right `width`'s and `height`'s.

Comment: I would suggest to use "bootstrap" grids:   http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I've allready tried to type some code and it works, but this was only by using the <table> in html, this works for some pictures, but not for the layout I want in the picture... :-(

Comment: You will need to create a grid system that is comprised of rows and columns. Each column in a row can be further sub-divided into another set of rows and columns if need be. For _NO1_ You'd have a row with two columns in it. The second column (on the right) would contain two rows. The first of those rows would contain three columns and the second row would contain two columns.

Comment: Oh grind-container is a good idea. Im going to look, how this works. As seen so far at the suggested site this is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If your image sizes are already as you want, you can use CSS `float: left` on all of them and simply put them into the HTML in their order from top-left to right-bottom.

You'll also need `margin-right` and `margin-bottom` on all of them, but organized in two or three different classes with different settings for these that you assign to the `<img>` tags as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do below the codes,

**NO:1 image positioning:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
.container{
    background-color: gray; margin: 0px auto; width: 950px ! important;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.col1{
    border: 1px solid rgb(238, 238, 238); margin-right: 20px; width: 25%; float: left;height: 500px;background-color: red;
}
.col2{
     border: 1px solid rgb(238, 238, 238); height: 500px; float: left; width: 72%;
}
.imgdiv {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 31.09%;
}
.imgdiv:last-child{
  margin-right:0 !important;
}

.sec_row_content{
     background-color: red;
     clear: both;
     height: 380px;
     margin-top: 20px;
     clear:both;/***we need to clear the position (float left or right)***/

}
</style>
</head>
<body style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
<div class="container" style="">
    <div class="col1" style="">
    </div>
    <div class="col2" style="">
        <!--row1--><div class="" style="height:100px;">
            <!--image1--><div class="imgdiv" style=""></div>
            <!--image2--><div class="imgdiv" style=""></div>
            <!--image3--><div class="imgdiv" style=""></div>
                   </div>
         <!--row2-->
                <div class="height:100px;margin-top:20px;clear:both;">

                   <div class="sec_row_content"></div>

                </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

NO:2 as the same split 4 divs for 4 colums and set the percentage width each 25% of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Oh men, this is pretty easy. Thank you for all answers yet. A grid-layout proposed by "user2340218" is very nice. After a few seconds I have created a good looking picture layout! But I have a new question: Is it possible to place an effect on a line ( a: hover ... )?

```
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 15px;
}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.col-md-1 {
width: 27.33%; 
}
</style>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">f<img src="row001.jpg"></div>
</div>
```